# The program has exited with Code 0 (HELP)

Tags: c++

> ```
> 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
> The thread 0x1168 has exited with code 1710096384 (0x65ee0000).
> The thread 0x2a98 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread 0x1114 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread 0x21a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The program '[10428] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> ```

Why when I go to debug a window pops up momentarily then goes away and I get these messages?

Answer (score 23):

Your program executed faster than you were able to read the output. You didn't specify your IDE but I deduce Visual Studio, in which case try pressing ctrl + F5.

Comment: Haha I just tried that and it worked! Thank you, this was my first and have to admit it is kind of fun

Comment: This worked for me 3 years on. Thanks for this.

Comment: This answer is a life saver